# What is the song playing in My Hero Academia season 2 episode 13 at 6:05?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

I hear this song in a lot of episodes but I can't seem to find it anywhere! Please help, I know for sure it's in season 2 episode 13 at 6:05

Comment: There is no ep26 on S2

Comment: It's listed as such in uh.... Hulu. It's actually just episode 13 I found out of season 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have not been wrong with the scene the song is:

Arararara? (あらららら？) by Yuki Hayashi.
It is the twelfth track of the album My Hero Academia Original Soundtrack.

The part that sounds in that scene is from the second 27-29 of the song onwards.

[Song in Youtube](https://youtu.be/HX1fn32Oinc?t=27)